# How to set Excel sheet name dynamically via JasperReports 6.x?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have to upgrade jasperreport-4.0.2 to jasperreport-6.5.1 I found some differences regarding export reports to excel format as

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JExcelApiExporter
```

Is deprecated and replaced by

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter
```

And many others things are also changed. 
As in jasperreport-4.0.2 I can change excel sheet names as by this code

```
JRAbstractExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JExcelApiExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

What is alternate for naming excel sheets in jasperreport-6.5.1 is?

Comment: I have successfully changed other properties like this
exporter.getPropertiesUtil().setProperty(XlsReportConfiguration.PROPERTY_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, "true");
exporter.getPropertiesUtil().setProperty(XlsReportConfiguration.PROPERTY_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, "true");
exporter.getPropertiesUtil().setProperty(XlsReportConfiguration.PROPERTY_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, "true");
But sheet names is still mystry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with the new API (comparing with 4.x version) you can solve the task in several ways.

***Using ReportExportConfiguration***

We can set sheet name using *SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration*, in thit case we should override *[getSheetNames()](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/AbstractXlsReportConfiguration.html#getSheetNames--)* method.

Java code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);

JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();

exporter.setConfiguration(new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration() {

    @Override
    public String[] getSheetNames() {
        return new String[]{"MyName"};
    }
});
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = null;
try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream);
    exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
    exporter.exportReport();
} finally {
    if (exporterOutput != null) {
        exporterOutput.close();
    }
}
```

Report template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Set sheet name via exporter's configuration" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="200" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <title>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Set sheet name via exporter's configuration]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The generated result will be:

[image: Generated result at MS Excel]

***Using report's parameter and net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name property***

The sheet name can be set with help of *[net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name)* property. In case we want set this name dynamically we can use report's parameter for passing the name.

Java code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("stringParam", "ZZZ");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);

JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();

exporter.setConfiguration(new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration());
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = null;
try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream);
    exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
    exporter.exportReport();
} finally {
    if (exporterOutput != null) {
        exporterOutput.close();
    }
}
```

The report's template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Set sheet name via parameter" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="200" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30">
                    <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$P{name}]]></propertyExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Set sheet name via parameter]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: Generated result at MS Excel]

---

More information about using xls/xlsx exporters:

- [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures)

Comment: SimpleReportExportConfiguration simpleReportExportConfiguration = new SimpleReportExportConfiguration();
    simpleReportExportConfiguration.setOffsetX(0);
    simpleReportExportConfiguration.setOffsetY(0);
    exporter.setConfiguration(simpleReportExportConfiguration);

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring clas

Comment: You are working wrong with generics. I did not set your code (and it should be a new question with your code and stacktrace), but seems to me that you are using `JRXlsxExporter`. It is declared as `public class JRXlsxExporter extends JRXlsAbstractExporter<XlsxReportConfiguration, XlsxExporterConfiguration, JRXlsxExporterContext>`. The `SimpleReportExportConfiguration` is not subclass of `XlsxReportConfiguration`

Comment: You should look at [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) & [Java Generics Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/index.html) & [Java Generics cheat sheet](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-generics-cheat-sheet/) & [Generics: How They Work and Why They Are Important](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/juneau-generics-2255374.html)